# Create a new column from two existing text columns in a DataFrame using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a Dataframe with two columns `"Start_location"` and `"end_location"`. I want to create a new column called `"location"` from the 2 previous columns with the following conditions.

If the values of `"start_location" == "end_location"`, then the value of `"location"` will be either of the values of the first two columns.
else, if the values of of `"start_location"` and `"end_location` are different, then values of `"Location"` will be `"start_location"-"end_location".`

An example of what I want is this.

```
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+
|   |  Start_location    |      End_location     |
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+
| 1 | Stratford          |      Stratford        |
| 2 | Bromley            |      Stratford        |
| 3 | Brighton           |      Manchester       |
| 4 | Delaware           |      Delaware         |
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

The result I want is this.

```
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|   |  Start_location    |      End_location     |   Location         |
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 1 | Stratford          |      Stratford        |   Stratford        |
| 2 | Bromley            |      Stratford        | Brombley-Stratford |
| 3 | Brighton           |      Manchester       | Brighton-Manchester|
| 4 | Delaware           |      Delaware         |    Delaware        |
+---+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

I would be happy if anyone can help.

PS- forgive me if this is a very basic question. I have gone through some similar questions on this topic but couldn't get a headway.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own function that does this and then use `apply` and a lambda function:

```
def get_location(start, end):
    if start == end:
        return start
    else:
        return start + ' - ' + end

df['location'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_location(x.Start_location, x.End_location), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Location'] = df[['start_location','end_location']].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else x[0] + '-' + x[1], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.select(condition, choice)`. To join start, use `.str.cat()` method

```py
import numpy as np

condition=[df['Start_location']==df['End_location'],df['Start_location']!= df['End_location']]
choice=[df['Start_location'], df['Start_location'].str.cat(df['End_location'], sep='_')]
df['Location']=np.select(condition, choice)

df
```

```
Start_location End_location             Location
1      Stratford    Stratford            Stratford
2        Bromley    Stratford    Bromley_Stratford
3       Brighton   Manchester  Brighton_Manchester
4       Delaware     Delaware             Delaware
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Numpy` to compare both columns.
Follow This code

```py
import numpy as np

df["Location"] =  np.where((df['Start_location'] == df['End_location'])
                           , df['Start_location'],df['Start_location']+"-"+ df['End_location'])

df
```

Output:

```py
    Start_location  End_location    Location
0   Stratford        Stratford      Stratford
1   Bromley          Stratford  Bromley-Stratford
2   Brighton         Manchester Brighton-Manchester
3   Delaware         Delaware        Delaware
```